# Facing a strange bug when starting a process in a Tomcat container. How to resolve it?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, batch-file, process

I have created a webapp that manages arbitrary jobs that were created by the users. One job copies some files to another folder and starts an external program. The external program is started using a batch-file and the batch-file sets some variables and starts another Java program that submits the files to a server. I start the batch-file like this:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("path/to/batch");

pb.directory("parent/folder/of/batch");

final Process p = pb.start();

p.waitFor();
```

The batch-file contains the following:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;<external-program.jar>
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

@echo off
set puser=****
set ppsw=****

java -jar <external-program.jar> %puser% %ppsw%
```

The process starts but does not finish and my webapp gets blocked. If I start the batch-file manually everything is fine. Now the really strange thing: If I focus the Tomcat window and shut down the server using `Ctrl-C` the process continues working and finishes with the expected result. How can that happen?

The last logs are:

```
[2015-01-14 14:31:39,514]DEBUG   860[main] - org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:70) - >> "GET /something HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2015-01-14 14:31:39,514]DEBUG   860[main] - org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:70) - >> "Authorization: Basic ****[\r][\n]"
[2015-01-14 14:31:39,514]DEBUG   860[main] - org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:70) - >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1[\r][\n]"
[2015-01-14 14:31:39,514]DEBUG   860[main] - org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:70) - >> "Host: some.host[\r][\n]"
[2015-01-14 14:31:39,514]DEBUG   860[main] - org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:70) - >> "[\r][\n]"
```

So I think that it is making a request to the server and then gets blocked. And somehow the servlet-container plays a role in that. I also tried to use Jetty but the problem remains the same. Using ports other than `80` does not solve the problem as well.

I am completly confused and I would be really glad if someone can help me.

P.S.: I am using Tomcat 8.0.15 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Does your process output on the console? You may try and redirect the process' std{in,out,err} (with `ProcessBuilder` you can do so) in this case

Comment: Yes it does in the Tomcat window. But I did not redirect the output. I don't understand why it is printed nevertheless.

Comment: Well, you should not be surprised; since you didn't specify any differently, spawned process will use the same file descriptors for input and output than tomcat itself. My hypothesis is that one such descriptor (either the input or one of the outputs, or both) are preventing the spawned process from operating normally (like it does from the console).

Comment: So you mean I should try to redirect std{in, out, err} of the new process? But where should I redirect it to? `ProcessBuilder` provides 3 methods to redirect the streams.

Comment: Well, your choice. To a file, for instance, which you can discard right after the process terminates, or keep for refernece in case of an error etc etc...

Comment: @fge Well that was the problem. The external program generated some exceptions and I think they were printed to stderr. Thank you very much for your fast help! If you write an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Answer redacted! Note also that I added a precision about `.waitFor()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if you don't redirect any descriptor (stdin, stdout or stderr; or whatever their equivalent on Windows is), they share it with the process which created them -- in your case, Tomcat.

It may be that the process tries and writes to stdout, stderr or both and that it blocks trying to write to it/them.

Try and redirect either to a file, for example, since with `ProcessBuilder` you can do so ([stdout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput-java.io.File-), [stderr](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectError-java.io.File-)).

Also, check for the return value of `.waitFor()`: this will be the exit value of the process. Since you invoke a jar, any exception thrown by `main()` which is uncaught will make the process exit with code 1 (which is why when you write programs yourself you should not use this exit code!).

Comment: I already check the value, but I never got a value, because the other process never terminated.